# Java: How to find the second char in a string?

Tags: java

So let say I have a String:

```
String line1 = "you can also view my (abbreviated)(resume.html) at lunch.";
```

and another String :

```
String line2 = "you can also view my(resume.html) at lunch.";
```

So I'm trying to take the substring of line2 to make the

```
line2 = "you can also view my resume.html at lunch."
```

and similarly with line1 so

```
line1 = "you can also view my (abbreviated) resume.html at lunch."
```

However when I try to use the code to make the string for line2 which I used for line 1 it has a problem since when I try to find the index of "(" and ")" it read them from (abbreviated) instead of the "(" and ")" from the resume.html.

So for example to change line 1 I would do

```
String ax = line1.substring(line1.indexOf("(") + 1, line1.indexOf(")"));
line1 = line1.substring(0,line1.indexOf("(")) + ax + line1.substring(line1.indexOf(")");
```

However when i do something similar for the first line it messes up.

I need help to write a single method or way that works for both of them.

Comment: Did you try with `line1 = line1.replace("(resume.html)", " resume.html")`?

Comment: or line1.replace("(","").replace(")","")

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ((lastIndexOf)) method instead of ((indexOf)) method, will look like this:

```
    String ax = line1.substring(line1.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, line1.lastIndexOf(")"));
    line1 = line1.substring(0,line1.lastIndexOf("(")) + ax +line1.substring(line1.lastIndexOf(")");
```